# Getting a reactjs SPA spidered without using node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, seo, reactjs

I'm building a reactjs based website that others will be deploying. It takes the form of a single page app with URL routing `/#like=this` and the final websites will be content rich. All of the content needs to be visible to search engine bots. Is there a way to do this (even a hacky one) that doesn't require isomorphic server-side rendering? In particular, I can't expect the end users to be able to serve pages with node/express.

Comment: Google can crawl client-side-rendered pages so if that's good enough then your are already covered.

Comment: @Hummlas This appears _not_ to be true, which is why there are lots of attempts at creating isomorphic or "universal" JS that needs to spun up server-side using node. I ran a test myself and google spidered the page but didn't capture the dynamic content.

Comment: http://searchengineland.com/tested-googlebot-crawls-javascript-heres-learned-220157

We've also confirmed this ourselves at my working place where we've created a SPA using React (not isomorphic/universal) and verified that it could be indexed by google.

Comment: @Hummlas Interesting... I reran the test with some tweaking and it looks like the page at / is getting spidered correctly, but anything after the anchor tag is ignored. Will look into /#! but from what I understand that makes a direct request for different content from the sever. There may be a .htaccess solution here?

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to do this (even a hacky one) that doesn't require isomorphic server-side rendering?

No

> In particular, I can't expect the end users to be able to serve pages with node/express.

Nodejs has nothing to do with this. The client does not know where the content is rendered.